# MUI Radio button group returning strings despite providing it with boolean values

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

I am building a form with RHF V7, MUI V5 and validating its data with yup.  The issue I am facing is that a radio button group is returning a string of 'true' or 'false' despite providing it with a boolean `true` or `false` value.

Additionally, I test the radio button value via `onChange={() => console.log(typeof item.value)}` and it logs `Boolean` every time yet, when I log the form data I get `{Radio: "true"}`.

[image]

here is the working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rhf-v7-radio-casting-string-wiou8

Any ideas?

Comment: If you read the api docs https://mui.com/api/radio-group/. Value says 'Value of the selected radio button. The DOM API casts this to a string.'

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @Richard. Additionally, upon further investigation, by design Input values will be cast as a string as per [MDM web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

Value: A [**DOMString**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) presenting the value of the radio button.

So, most likely, this is why the example above is returning a string.